# Preventing a hyperlink from looping with the rest of the table?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have a table that presents grouped data, and has 'buttons' in the form of hyperlinks for users to view more information about that grouped data as a whole. However the button also loops with every row, when ideally I would only like it to show once for every group. I have tried moving around my @foreach loops but keep getting errors that the requested ID does not exist in this collection instance.

[image]

For example, I am trying to get those links to only appear once in each group (once in 1 and 2 like in the image).

Code:

```
        <tr>
            @foreach ($grouped as $mealplan)
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
              Recipe Information
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
              Meal Plan Info
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
              Print
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
              Archive
            </th>
          <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            Recipe Name
          </th>
          <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            Day
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
      @foreach ($mealplan as $recipe)
        <tr>
          <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
             <a href="recipeinformation/{{$recipe->Recipe_ID}}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">More</a>
           </td>
           <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
              <a href="/MealPlanDisplay/modal/{{$recipe->MealPlan_ID}}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">Meal Plan Info</a>
            </td>
           <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
              <a href="printpreviewingredients/{{$recipe->MealPlan_ID}}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">Print Ingredient List</a>
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
               <a href="/Archive/{{$recipe->MealPlan_ID}}" class="text-red-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">Archive</a>
             </td>
          <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
            {{$recipe->recipe_name}}
      </td>
      <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
        {{$recipe->Day}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </br>
  @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Any advice on where to move the loops, or how to only get the links to show once per group in the table would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you not use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable and check whether it's the first iteration in the foreach. If it is, show the view more, if it's not, either show something else or replace it with an &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

The concept of doing such iteration is as follows:

**Notice the comments in the code**

```
<table>
    {{--/*Comment: iterate through the groups to show sub-groups*/--}}
    @foreach ($group as $sub_group)
        <thead>
            {{--/*Comment: the group head row is here*/--}}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{--/*Comment: iterate through the sub-group to show its items*/--}}
            @foreach ($sub_group as $item)
                {{--/*Comment: put here a condition to filter items*/--}}
                {{--/*Comment: in your case you want the "MORE" link to only 
                appear in the first row so we will check iteration index. 
                Luckily, we have $loop variable in Laravel so we don't have to count
                the index manually. The condition will be like this:
                1- if loop is in round "1", we should print the link inside the <td>.
                2- if not we should print empty <td> */--}}

                {{--/*Comment: Print the "more" link only on the first iteration */--}}
                @if($loop->iteration == 1)
                    <td>{{--/*Comment: put the link here */--}}</td>
                @else
                    <td>{{--/*Comment: empty cell*/--}}</td>
                @endif
                {{--/*Comment: then here comes the rest of the <td>s */--}}
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

And here is an Edit to your code

```
<table class="table" style="magin-left:200px">
    @foreach ($grouped as $mealplan)
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"
                    class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                    Recipe Information
                </th>
                <th scope="col"
                    class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                    Meal Plan Info
                </th>
                <th scope="col"
                    class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                    Print
                </th>
                <th scope="col"
                    class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                    Archive
                </th>
                <th scope="col"
                    class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                    Recipe Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col"
                    class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                    Day
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
            @foreach ($mealplan as $recipe)
                <tr>
                    {{-- Print the "more" link only on the first iteration --}}
                    @if ($loop->iteration == 1)
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
                            <a href="recipeinformation/{{ $recipe->Recipe_ID }}"
                                class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">More</a>
                        </td>
                    @else
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium"></td>
                    @endif
                    <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
                        <a href="/MealPlanDisplay/modal/{{ $recipe->MealPlan_ID }}"
                            class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">Meal Plan Info</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
                        <a href="printpreviewingredients/{{ $recipe->MealPlan_ID }}"
                            class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">Print Ingredient
                            List</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
                        <a href="/Archive/{{ $recipe->MealPlan_ID }}"
                            class="text-red-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">Archive</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                        {{ $recipe->recipe_name }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                        {{ $recipe->Day }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

[Outcome of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdbs1.png)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll put that into my consideration on answering any questions. That was just my first try of interacting on stackoverflow.